# Give console access to non-admin user in SCVMM 2012 R2

Tags: scvmm

Is it possible to allow a non-admin user to connect to the local console of a virtual machine through System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2012 R2?  As far as I can tell, Application Admin would allow a user to deploy and manage their own VM, but I'm looking to just allow multiple users the ability to connect to an existing VM.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that rather than trying to get SCVMM to jump through hoops it isn't comfortable jumping through, the best way to do this might be RDP for a Windows server or SSH for a Linux server.

Comment: Most of their admin work is done via RDP.  But if RDP isn't working, or the server is powered off, they need to be able to get to the console and see what's going on.

Comment: I wrote a blog few years ago, still applicable
http://www.prof-its.be/wp/private-cloud/vmm-delegated-admins/
should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

yes, and its called VMM delegated admin
you can configure this in the settings pane - Security - User Roles
when you add non admin users to this group they will receive rights to start/stop vm, migrate VMs and such, but they will not be able to change any VMM settings

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've set this up for a test user, but I can't seem to see where I tell VMM what VMs they should have access to.  If I log in as that user, I can see everything; these users should only have access to their own VMs, not the rest.  This was fairly easy to do in vCenter; can VMM do this?